# Should I use an index or cache to solve simple slow queries?

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

Here's an example of a simple query using Laravel 4 eager loading that's running slow because it has a large number of records in the table.

```
select * from `media` where `extension` in ('jpg', 'JPG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG', 'png', 'PNG', 'bmp', 'BMP', 'gif', 'GIF', 'nef', 'NEF', 'svg', 'SVG', 'tiff', 'TIFF') and `media`.`album_id` in ('1', '2')
```

And here's the explain on it:

```
Params
id  1
select_type SIMPLE
table   media
type    ALL
possible_keys   null
key null
key_len null
ref null
rows    10480
Extra   Using where
```

Should I add an index in this circumstance or is my only option caching the result since it doesn't involve more than one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is not changing very often, then you should cache the result to speed up your transaction.

If the data changes regularly - you should optimize the query to increase the speed.